# Set Up a test when the testing class extends another class with dependencies - PHPUnit

Tags: php, dependency-injection, phpunit

I have a class `example{}` which extends another class `example2{}`. The class `example2{}` has 2 dependencies in its constructor.

In my `exampleTest{}` i have a `setUp()` method in order to instantiate the `example{}` class which i want to test.

The problem is that the constructor of the `example2{}` class throws an error about the 2 dependencies.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: Mock dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

In your child class __construct() method, you should take in the same arguments (or more if needed) as the parent class. And in the method body, call parent::__construct($var) :

```
class Animal
{
    private $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal
{
    private $age;

    public function __construct($name, $age)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->age = $age;
    }
}
```